# Error while pressing debug java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, while-loop, queue

I have this problem when i press debug, the error refer to while loop in line 142

[image: image of the code part 1]

[image: image of the code part 2]

[image: Image of the error]

Comment: You didnt save your file(Q3.java)

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Please share all code/errors etc as *text* in the question, not as images, or hyperlinks.

Comment: Generally speaking, this behavior is indicative of a bug in Eclipse.  However, you haven't shown us enough detail to allow anyone to identify the particular bug.